# Is there a way to decode the hex string in the Shopify order complete URL?

Tags: r, hex, shopify, matomo

I'm running Matomo to get clickstream data from a Shopify ecommerce site and rather than going through the pain of getting ecommerce tracking working I'd like to extract the order-id from the thank-you URL. I can then join the clickstream data to ERP order details.

An example URL is:

```
https://example.com/123456789/orders/d85e0fcf1a7e9e1c3c441c0777326775
```

... where `d85e0fcf1a7e9e1c3c441c0777326775` is an actual order number.

I tried to do a standard hex decode, but the result was garbage.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the hash isn't standard encryption. It is however the `order_hash` presented through the Shopify orders REST API. I ended up creating a private Shopify app and using the [shopr R package](https://github.com/ben519/shopr) to get the order data which includes the `order_hash`. The order hash can be extracted from the Matomo data URL as above and joined.